# Screen resolution on iPhone 6 (Plus) Display-Zoom in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios9

As far as I know, there is still no possibility to toggle Display-Zoom on the iPhone simulator. Therefore, could somebody that owns an iPhone 6 (Plus) confirm that these values for the screen resolution are returned by `view.bounds.size` when `Display-Zoom` mode is toggled on and the phone is aligned in portrait mode (point metrics):

- iPhone 6 + Display-Zoom:        (320.0, 568.0)
- iPhone 6 Plus + Display-Zoom:   (375.0, 667.0)

**UPDATE (27.05.16):**

Okay it looks like the iPhone 6+ in `Display-Zoom` mode is the same as a normal iPhone 6 and a iPhone 6 in `Display-Zoom` mode is the same as a iPhone 5 in terms of screen resolutions. I hope also that `view.bounds.size` return values are accordingly (please confirm!).

But what image assets (@2x or @3x) are used when an iPhone 6+ turns from normal mode to `Display-Zoom` mode? Are still @3x assets used although the screen resolution is that of a normal iPhone 6 (which uses @2x assets) ?

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure display zoom drops down 1 phone res,  so iphone 6 -> iphone 5, iphone 6+ -> iphone 6,  so yes it will be 667x375

Comment: Here is an article confirming: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/explaining-display-zoom-on-iphone-6-and-6-plus/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you know how to handle a switch of the Display-Zoom toggle while the app is still running in the background? I can't imagine that right now...

Comment: you can check on the notification that the application will be active when you need to grab the screen size.

Comment: Ok great, thank you! if you formulate a short answer, I'll check it as the solution..

Comment: nah, somebody will hopefully give you the correct answer from apple docs with examples,  I am too lazy to look all that up today for ya.

Comment: No problem, you already did a great job for me :-)

Comment: @KnightOfDragon: Any ideas about the "update" in my original question?

Comment: View size wouldnt change,  you would need to use UIScreen